# What file permissions should I set on web root?

Tags: nginx

I use Ubuntu Server 10.10 and have installed Nginx web server with `apt-get install nginx`. It creates a default web page at `/var/www/nginx-default/` and that directory has the permissions `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root`.

When I access the default site on `http://localhost/` I get this message on the page `403 Forbidden`.

How should I set the file permissions on the www root so I can secure access the web pages? Or is there something else that I have to change?

Comment: **NOTE:** the *whole full path* to your final folder must be accessible! Not even one folder in the middle.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I usually stick to a `755` (or `rwxr-xr-x`) on my web root, but I do not think this is the issue you're running into since your directory is already set to that.  `nginx` should have access to your directory.  The question then becomes the permissions (or existence of) the file you're trying to access.  The files within your directory will need to be readable by the user `nginx` is running as.  I usually leave these files set to a `755` (the same as the directory).  You can change the entire directory by doing `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/nginx-default/`.

If there is not an index file in the directory, however, you will still get the same error.  The index file is used when you request a directory that doesn't have directory listings enabled.  The most common index file is `index.html`.  This default can be edited in your config, however, using something like:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
}
```

If you want `nginx` to generate a list of files in that directory for you, simply turn on [directory indexing](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpAutoindexModule), like so:

```
location  /  {
  autoindex  on;
}
```

Comment: No I have an `index.html` in that directory.

Comment: What permissions does your `index.html` have, then?

Comment: Thanks, the confiugration file actually pointed to `/var/www/` and the generated `index.html` was placed in `/var/www/nginx-default/` so I had to copy that file with `cp /var/www/nginx-default/index.html /var/www/` after that I could visit the site with my web browser.

Comment: Better to update your nginx confg than host that file out of `www`

Answer (score 82):

I would suggest changing the group of your webroot to `www-data`, the user used by nginx and also php5-fpm.

For example:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /webdirectory
sudo chmod -R 0755 /webdirectory
```

where my-user is your own account (which enables you to put the files easy in your webroot without sudo).

Comment: Thanks, the commands executed without any problems, but I still get `403 Forbidden` when acessing it with a web browser.

Comment: @Jonas, I would suggest to check your nginx error log to see what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error, it was in the error log. See my comment to Jacks answer.

Comment: What about new files?

Comment: @MatteoContrini use `chmod 2755 webdirectory/` so they are stored with the same permissions and rights

Comment: what's the '2' ?

Comment: @realtebo it is the `setgid bit`, the details are too long for a comment, read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#:~:text=The%20Unix%20access%20rights%20flags,to%20change%20behaviour%20in%20directories.) but in short: `The Unix access rights flags setuid and setgid (short for "set user ID" and "set group ID") allow users to run an executable with the file system permissions of the executable's owner or group respectively and to change behaviour in directories.`